# How to detect if HealthKit data is set from a device?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to fetch user steps from HealthKit and realised that users can add manually steps which I don't want to fetch. (For instance if they're cheating and setting 50k steps on one day).

So I was thinking for a solution how to solve this problem and found out that maybe I could just filter all the result and fetch the data if the data was set by a device. I mean it could be set by an iPhone, but it can also be set by an Apple Watch.

#### Here's how it looks when a user adds his/hers own steps manually in the Health app:

[image: Steps added by an user]

#### Here's how it looks when the steps are added by a device:

[image: Steps added by a watch]

So when the data are set by a device, we can see more information from the device in the Health-app rather than a user whom setting the data manually.

**The question is:** How do I find if there are a device in the result?

#### My current code to fetch the results:

```
func getSteps(completion: @escaping (Double, Error?) -> ()) {
    let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
           
    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: stepsQuantityType, predicate: nil, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil){ query, results, error in
        if let error = error {
            // Handle error
        } else if let results = results, !results.isEmpty {
            for result in results {
                // Detect and add result if result is from a device
            }
        }
    }

    HKHealthStore().execute(query)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realised that I can detect if a device does exist by `result.device` where `device` is an optional value. By doing so I can check if the value is `nil` or not.

```
func getSteps(completion: @escaping (Double, Error?) -> ()) {
    let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!


    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: stepsQuantityType, predicate: nil, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil){ query, results, error in
        if let error = error {
            // Handle error
        } else if let results = results, !results.isEmpty {
            for result in results {
                if result.device != nil {
                    // Result is from a device
                } else {
                    // Not a device
                }
            }
        }
    }

    HKHealthStore().execute(query)
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem but I solved it by filtering sources... which is very slow.  Does your method have any edges cases (combining wearable + phone steps ?) or works perfectly in production ?

Comment: It was such a long time ago, the app is in production and I didn't find any lag issues @NikhilMuskur

Comment: Cool then I'll implement this check :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let predicateAvoidManuallyLoggedData = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey: HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered, operatorType: .notEqualTo, value: true)
```

use above predicate with HKSample or Statistics queries.

you may also combine predicates like this

```
  let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: 
  [predicateSource, predicateTimePeriod, predicateAvoidManuallyLoggedData])
```